New to Blender: Image texture appears in viewport but disappears in camera view
I have put an image texture on a plane to serve as a background image; however, while I can see the texture in the viewport, it disappears when I try to look at it through the camera which makes it impossible to know if the camera angle is right. I have included screenshots of how the texture appears when I click into camera view vs how it appears in viewport.

I see you are using a plane with a texture on it, are you planning to render the scene with the background? The camera may be clipping through the image so you can't see it. You can also attach a .blend file via https://blend-exchange.com, you can remove the jet and clean up the scene so the file is smaller.

I agree with @KISKAart that the clipping distance might be the problem here (there are individual settings for 3D Viewport and camera), the other thing which I have to ask as long as I do not have the file to check for myself: there are several objects in the Outliner which are hidden in the viewport but visible for render. Could they be obstructing the view?
